# Translate sndarray into a number based on time in python?

Tags: python, audio, pygame

I just found out about the sndarray module in pygame, and I want to use it to translate an audio waveform into a number so that I can do something such as scale a rectangle etc based on audio. Here's some code I've written:

```
audio = pygame.mixer.Sound("example.ogg")
audio.play(-1)

audArray = pygame.sndarray.array(audio)

ticks = pygame.time.get_ticks()
wavForm = audArray[ticks*16] #ticks*16 based on audio rate or something like that
```

This is where I'm stuck. I'm not really sure what the wavForm object means or how to translate it into something I could use for the above example. Thanks for any help.

Comment: `pygame.time.get_ticks()` gives number of ticks since you start program ("time" since you start program) - as for me it has nothing to do with sndarray.

Comment: yeah, I know. Since the sound will play when the program starts, I can use it to reference the point in the snd array that it's at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made something like this - but I don't know whether it has sense.

I used some `ogg` file and I got `freq` over 22 000 bytes per second (it's 22kHz).
I use `clock.tick(freq)` to get 22 000 loops per second (and print one value from array per loop)
but I don't know whether PyGame can make 22 000 loops per second.

```
import pygame
import pygame.mixer

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

#-----

audio = pygame.mixer.Sound("example.ogg")
print 'sound length (in seconds):', audio.get_length()

audio_array = pygame.sndarray.array(audio)
print 'array length (in  bytes):', len(audio_array)

freq = len(audio_array)/audio.get_length() # frequences (loops per seconds)
print 'freq / bytes per second:', freq

#-----

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

raw_input("\npress ENTER ")

audio.play(-1)

for left, right in audio_array:
    #current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    #play_time = current_time - start_time

    print left, right

    clock.tick(freq)
```

Comment: ok, so the two values are the left and the right. What do they actually represent? As mentioned originally, I'd like to scale an object, or something similar, based on these values, which I can't really do if I just use the values because 1) there are two different values and 2) they're negative sometimes.

Comment: ok, so I think just using the absolute value works. I'm still not exactly sure why they're negative sometimes, though.

Comment: I call it `left`, `right` because I think it is left i right channel but I'm not sure. There are negative values because it is interger with sign (as in C/C++) (ex. -127..128) not integer without sign (ex. 0..256) - see also `size` argument in [pygame.mixer.pre_init()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.pre_init) - and try 16 in place of -16, maybe it helps.